# Definite integral of partial fractions?

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, partial-fractions

So I'm to find the definite integral of a function which I'm to convert into partial fractions.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{2x^2+3x+1}\,dx$$

Converting to partial fractions I get...
$\frac{A}{2x+1} + \frac{B}{x+1}$ with $A = 4$ and $B = -2$

Thus the definite integral is...

$$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \left(\frac{4}{2x+1}-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\,dx \\[8pt]
& =[4\ln|2x+1| - 2\ln|x+1|]_0^1 \\[8pt]
& = 4\ln|3|-2\ln|2| - (4\ln|1| - 2\ln|1|) \\[8pt]
& = 4\ln|3| - 2\ln|2| - 0 \\[8pt]
& = 2(2\ln|3|-\ln|2|) \\[8pt]
& = 2\ln\left|\frac{9}{2}\right|
\end{align}
$$

However, the answer in the book gives $2\ln|\frac{3}{2}|$ as do online integral calculators, so I imagine I've done something wrong, but can't for the life of we work out what since I keep getting the same values for A and B and the same answer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neglected the chain rule:
$$
\int \frac{4}{2x+1} \, dx = 2\ln|2x+1|+C \ne 4\ln|2x+1|+C.
$$

Comment: Thank you! That's what I did wrong.